# How to import XML testcase in SoapUI?

Tags: soapui

I created XML testcases in notepad, and I want to import and execute testcases in SoapUI. Can you please help me?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because ["Can Someone Help Me" is not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0):

You mean you wrote a SOAP XML request in Notepad and now you want to run it via SoapUI?  If so, you can paste it into a new request in SoapUI.  This assumes that  you have created a project in SoapUI based on a WSDL, you've created sample requests from that WSDL, and now you want to plug in some "real" requests.

Answer (score -1):

Save your notepad (where you have written xml test case) it as a XML and select for Import Project...